# Additional data series not plotting on dual axis GG plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatterplot with three series and two axes.

Here's a subset of data:

| sensor1Current | sensor1ReVoltage | sensor1CeVoltage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 114.98412 | 0.81225 | 0.537 |
| 1293.7681 | 1.71975 | 1.71975 |
| 0.43690163 | 0.81 | 0.738 |

The first axis is Current, the second is Voltage.

I'm trying to create a chart like this [image]

With the following code:

```
  geom_point( data=test, aes(x=clean_time,y=sensor1Current), color="blue") + 
  geom_point( data=test, aes(x=clean_time,y=sensor1ReVoltage), color="orange") +
  geom_point( data=test,aes(x=clean_time,y=sensor1CeVoltage), color="gray") +
  
  scale_y_continuous(
    
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "Sensor Current (nA)",
    
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000 ,name="Electrode Voltage (V)")
  )
```

But this is what I'm getting. When I switch the lines for ReVoltage and CeVoltage, the colors just flip but they all hang at 0. It seems like only Current is plotting, the additional series ReVoltage and CeVoltage are not. What am I doing wrong? Are they not being assigned to the secondary axis?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your x axis is a categorical rather than numeric variable.

Comment: I'm on mobile so excuse then non-inlined codes. It seems that your 'clean_time' variable is of interpreted by R as a character vector. Before running the plot command you could run 'test$clean_time <- as.date(test$clean_time)'.

Comment: @brendbech I converted it to POSIXct and updated the graph. The thing is that it looks like the first series is plotting appropriately whether char or time, but the second and third series are not.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: @Quinten There are many hundred rows and dozens of variables, but the ones relevant here are in a table above. The variables in question have the same length with no NAs.